# Webdriver: Click on button's part for open color chooser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, color-picker

I use Selenium to test some web-product in my company.
Product has button, which open dialog to choose color. I think it's created using 'extJS' (I'm not so sure).
But then i click to any part of that button, using Webdriver, it's always just set current selected color, but newer opened dialog window to select color.

I found similar button on some random site, which has similiar  behavior.

[Link to site with button on developer.yahoo.com](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example11.html)

So in source of the page you can see, that there is no specific element for right part of button, with down-oriented arrow.
So xPath

```
//*[@id='color-picker-button']
```

describe button in all,right part and left part.

But every child element of this describe only left part of this button, so right part with arrow has no any specific xPath to click in my WebDriver text.
I also tried things like

```
driver.action.move_to(element, coordinate_right, coordinate_down).perform
```

but it has no effect for me.

So in general my question is :

How to open color selector window on [that Yahoo page](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example11.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SendKeys() method and send the "down arrow" key to the control (C#):

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
```

That should open it right up.

Comment: Thanks, it's work. I never think about it. How did you get that answer?

Comment: what exactly is the value fo Keys.ArrowDown ?

Comment: It's a unicode character - see: http://unicodelookup.com/#57365/1
Make sure you use IE or FF to view that link, it won't render in chrome...