# Selenium WebDriver - Have a button with two click zones and selenium is not clicking properly

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Ok guys,

I'm QAing a claims application by guidewire and this is where im running into an issue.

The header area has header buttons and one of them is Claims, this button has two click zones, when you click on the claims label it recalls the last claim you had opened, when you click the down arrow, it opens and shows you more options.

The option I want to get to is "New Claim"

FirePath shows me two seperate xPaths

For the claim label: .//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab-btnInnerEl']
For the downarrow label: .//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab-btnWrap']
Once the downarrow is initiated the xpath for New Claim: .//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab:ClaimTab_FNOLWizard-textEl']

However when I write my script:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab-btnWrap']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab:ClaimTab_FNOLWizard-textEl']")).click();
```

it constantly keeps clicking on the wrong area and recalling the last claim and the script fails.

Here is a screencast of the behavior expected:
http://screencast.com/t/jtI1kGkfmXK

and here is basically what its doing
http://screencast.com/t/s2Q6VrbJl

What can I do to circumvent this issue? Its driving me crazy.

Comment: can you please add the html code snippet related to this Claim tab button ? I can base my answer on that because I am guessing there is a tweak needed in the xpath.

Comment: hi @Subh here it is:

http://screencast.com/t/KJO9MmAC

Comment: also @Subh notice what happens in this next  video when I overlay the HTML, it shows the down arrow highlighted but it also highlights the claim portion -

http://screencast.com/t/MBUnVo5nFarO

Answer (score 0):

You need to click open the window and wait for that to open.So,
**Some wait needed after your first click**
Then, You probably have to use `switchTo()` to set focus on the newly opened dropdown window. Some examples how to use it are [here](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2014/02/example-of-handling-multiple-browser.html). After that use a textbase search for finding your element. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003495/selenium-xpath-to-search-for-an-element-in-a-table-and-click-on-radio-button).

EDIT:
I found text base search helps a lot in such cases.
try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab-btnWrap']")).click();
//use some static delay for now. But, really you should use some fluent wait for the element to appear.

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[.='New Claim']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi,

I understand, however the problem is that webdriver will not properly click on this dual function button, Webdriver is not clicking on the proper area. It keeps clicking the the wrong functional area of the button even though they both have different xpaths so we were trying to call it directly but that isnt working either

Answer (score 0):

I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9380046/4193730)

Try this code, and see if it works:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab-btnWrap']")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Comment: Hi @Subh no luck it did not find the element properly, http://screencast.com/t/7UYMUz3shIX

i triggered it manually

Answer (score 0):

Well what I can gather is you have to get to the "New Claim" span and click it.

You can use Javascriptexecutor and directly click on the "New Claim" even without bringing it up. It helps that your intended element to be clicked has a unique id.

So you can use the following :

```
var js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

 if (js != null)
{
    js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('TabBar:ClaimTab:ClaimTab_FNOLWizard-textEl').click();") 
}
```

Comment: Hi - this is not working, it is not finding the element:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...) is null

I have tried 3 different ID's but it seems to be a new window which opens

Comment: Are you sure its not part of a frame ? If frames are involved your Javascript changes...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had to use the actions class but this worked!
Its a little weird but it works

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Claim"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    Action dropdown = builder.clickAndHold(element)
    .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) 
    .build();
    dropdown.perform();



    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab:ClaimTab_FNOLWizard-textEl']")).click();
```